# GStreamer Flow for OS X Desktop

Tags: macos, gstreamer, desktop

I am a new user of GStreamer on Mac OS X EL Capitan 10.11.3. 
I have installed GStreamer from http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/osx/1.7.1/ with .pkg (version devel and standard version).
I am trying to catch the desktop to send it to an other display. 
I streamed my webcam, with success :

```
$ gst-launch wrappercamerabinsrc mode=2  ! video/x-raw, width=320, height=240 !  osxvideosink
```

But I do not find the descriptor for my desktop anywhere.
Do you know the equivalent of ximagesrc from Ubuntu to Mac OS X ?

Could you help me ?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `avfvideosrc` source element, `videoscale` element to downsample resolution of your video stream, then you need to use `videoconvert` (in case video sink and your stream have no common pixel format to use).

```
gst-launch-1.0 avfvideosrc capture-screen=true ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! osxvideosink
```

Put `videoscale` before `videoconvert` to avoid extra work done (the less pixels to convert - the faster your pipeline).

Answer (score 0):

`avfvideosrc capture-screen=true` should do the trick as the source element.